# Magento multistore / rewrite img src

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento

I have 2 magento multistores:

One is set up on aaaa.domain.com
Second is set up on bbbb.domain.com

The problem is that all the img src's from bbbb.domain.com start with bbbb.domain.com (returning a 404 error) when they should start with aaaa.domain.com(shows the image)

How can I fix this problem? I thought of htaccess but I got 0 knowledge on it.

Comment: create symbolic link of media folder in your bbbb domain's directory

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. more info please...

Comment: Follow first method if you have different folder.. 

https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-configure-multiple-magento-storefronts.html